# Problema comprimiendo archivos con tar

Tags: linux, bash

El comando

```
tar -cvfz archivo.tar.gz fichero1 fichero2 fichero3
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
tar: archivo.tar.gz: No se puede stat: No existe el fichero o el directorio
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

No entiendo qué es lo que puede estar mal en mi comando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas haciendo `tar fz ...`

Con eso, le estas indicando que cree un archivo de nombre z.

Pon la `z` antes de la f

Comment: Total, ese era el problema. No sabía que el orden en el aspecto de las opciones importara. Solucionado. Muchas gracias

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, por favor, acéptala (dale al simbolito del check). Encantado de ayudar.

Comment: Claro, claro. Pero no me dejaba darle hasta pasados 10 minutos.

Comment: Perdona, no me di cuenta del tiempo. Gracias.